# How could I assign keybinding for "<M-tab>"

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

I would like to use <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> keybindings in `emacs` to correct a spelling instead of using the `ispell`s default one. Please note that I am open `emacs` in terminal.

I have tried following but it did not help. Is there any way to fix it?

- `(global-set-key (kbd "<M-tab>") 'helm-flyspell-correct)`
- `(global-set-key (kbd "<M-;>") 'helm-flyspell-correct)`

Comment: Try `(kbd "M-;")`. Generally, use the syntax that `C-h k` shows you for the key sequence.

Comment: Does your OS steal `<M-tab>`, perhaps? What happens when you use it?

Comment: IIRC, you are doing this in terminal emacs, right? Does `M-<tab>` even exist? I gave you a recipe in a comment to another question on how to check for that.

Comment: Yes I am doing it inside the terminal. I think it does autocorrent suggestions for `ispell`, but shows the work on the mini-buffer. Instead I wanted to use `helm-flyspell-correct`.
// When I use `M-tab` inside Safari or other windows it keeps moving to next element in the page.

Comment: @Drew I have also tried `(kbd "M-;")` , it just enters the character `;`

Comment: Does your terminal even support those key sequences? It sounds like it doesn't. You might need to provide more info here about your use of Emacs in terminal mode.

Comment: I have manage to make `M-;` work but `M-<tab>` always takes action for its default behavior @Drew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `(kbd "M-<tab>")`. Note that `M-` is outside the <>

Comment: I have following `(global-set-key (kbd "M-<tab>") 'helm-flyspell-correct)`: but still it does not recognize `helm-flyspell-correct`, hence do the defualt `ispell`'s suggestions

Comment: Its possible that a binding in another keymap is shadowing the one in your global keymap. The global keymap is the last place it is check. You can check what function is being called with `C-h k`.

Comment: I got following for `alt-tab`: `C-M-i runs the command elpy-company-backend (found in elpy-mode-map), which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in ‘elpy.el’.

It is bound to C-M-i, <menu-bar> <Elpy> <Complete>.

(elpy-company-backend COMMAND &optional ARG &rest IGNORED)

A company-mode backend for Elpy.
`

Comment: Ok, so that means that your global binding is shadowed by the binding in elpy-mode-map. If you want to make the binding available when editing a python file you would have to remove the binding from the elpy-mode-map. You can do so with `(define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-<tab>") nil)`